# DataGridViewRow resize event?

Tags: .net, datagridview

is there an event triggered when a DataGridViewRow is resized? or any other way I can catch when that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the DataGridView [RowHeightChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheightchanged.aspx) event.